# AngularJS +1.5 How can a Parent controller pass data to a component Controller

Tags: angularjs, inheritance, scope, angularjs-scope

I have a component like:

[Check Plunkr Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/XGJA1NPlUV6etLTYcsQE)   ( Updated and Working with the solution :) Thanks )

my-component.js declaration

```
 (function() {
  'use strict';
  angular
    .module('app')
    .component("myComponent", {
      bindings: { obj: "=" },
      controller: "ComponentController",
      controllerAs: "vm",
      template: 
        '<section class="result"><h2>{{vm.title}}</2>' + 
        '<h3>Using the Parent Controller values</h3>' +
        '<ul><li>{{ vm.obj.a }}</li><li>{{vm.obj.b}}</li></ul>' +
        '<h3>Using the Children controller values:'+
        '<ul class="component-controller"><li>{{ vm.copiedObj.a }}</li><li>{{vm.copiedObj.b}}</li></ul>' +
        '</section>'
    });

  })();
```

my-component controller

```
 (function() {
  'use strict';
  angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('ComponentController', ComponentController);

  function ComponentController() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.title = "I'm the Children controller"

    vm.copiedObj = vm.obj;   // This should store the myObj variable located in the MainController
  }

  })();
```

and a Parent Controller

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular
    .module('app', []);
})();


// app.controller.js
// ///////////////////
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('MainController', MainController);

  function MainController() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.title = "I'm the Parent controller";

    vm.myObj = {
      a: "I'm the first value",
      b: "I'm the second value"
    };

  }
  })();
```

So if i have a template like

```
  <body ng-controller="MainController as vm">

    <h2>{{vm.title}}</h2>

    <my-component obj="vm.myObj"></my-component> 

  </body>
```

The important line is where i have obj="vm.myObj"  right ?
I have something wrong because isn't even taking the vm.title :S

I don't want just to print the vm.myObj values into the component,
i want the vm.obj.value from the ParentController to be accessible & stored in the ComponentController.

Comment: `<my-component obj="vm.obj"></my-component>` should work....

Comment: well, your example doesn't show you actually *using* the value you passed in, so it's not really obvious what your specific problem might be.

Comment: Hi, totally true, i updated the post with a sample on Plunkr where i hope all can understand better what i'm trying to achieve, thanks.

Comment: @HéctorLeón this requires the parent controller to use controller as syntax correct?

Comment: Yes @Winnemucca, exactly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way we do it with components is using the ***bindings*** property. It’s simplified version of the directives’s ***scope*** and ***bindToController*** properties combined.

In a directive, the ***scope*** property allows us to define whether we want to inherit or isolate the $scope. That choice has, with time, been deduced to a sensible default to almost always make our directives have isolate scope. And with the addition of the ***bindToController*** property, we can define which properties we want to pass down to the isolate scope and bind directly to the controller.

In a component, with the ***bindings*** property this repetitive process is removed as the $scope by default is always isolate.

**General Example:**

```
// directive
.directive("myDirective", function myDirective() {
    return {
        scope: {},              // isolate scope
        bindToController: {
            value: "="          // two-way binding
        }
    };
});

// component
.component("myComponent", {
    bindings: {
        value: "="              // two-way binding
    }
});
```

**Detailed Example:**

```
angular
    .module("myApp")
    .controller("MyController", function MyController() {
        var vm = this;

        vm.myObj = {
            a: 1,
            b: 2
        };
    })
    .component("myComponent", {
        bindings: { value: "=" },
        controller: "MyComponentController",
        controllerAs: "vm",
        template: "<ul><li>vm.value.a</li><li>vm.value.b</li></ul>"
    });
```

In your template, you can pass down the data like so:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as vm">
    <my-component value="vm.myObj"></my-component> 
</div>
```

As explained above, the data is bound to and accessible in the (component's) controller by default.

Note that we’re using ***two-way*** binding here. Another addition that is available as of version 1.5 and is specific to components is the ***<*** symbol which denotes ***one-way*** bindings. Check out the “**Component-based application architecture**” section in the [official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i didn't get this working, i updated the post with a Link to Plunkr sample with our code merged, but still failing :S

Comment: I created **[new one](http://plnkr.co/edit/Cd3lp6ve7gcQORcUQpJC?p=preview)** as there are quite a few issues with yours. I hope this helps you understand components better. Cheers!

Comment: @DimitarRusev we should be able to access a controller property values like "myObj" by simply binding them to the value correct?  No need for require?

Answer (score 0):

1. In the above code, first issue is component does not have "bind" property instead it has "bindings" property.
2. Second is to pass the value from the parent controller to component via "obj" attribute.

I have corrected it and implemented the code as per your requirements:

```
<div ng-controller="ParentController as vm">
<my-component obj="vm.obj"></my-component>
</div>

    .controller('ParentController', ParentController)
    .component('myComponent', {
      bindings: {
        obj: '='
      },
      controller : function() {

      },
controllerAs:'vm',
      template: '<h1>Whatever <br>{{vm.obj.value}}<br>{{vm.obj.value2}}</h1>'

    });

      function ParentController( ) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.obj = {
          value : 1,
          value2: 2
        }
      };
```

Hope it will help you to solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i don't know where i have the error, please check my repo on plunkr :)

Comment: Two issues: 1. Replace "MyComponentController" by "ComponentController"    2. In vm.objStoredInComponentController = obj;, obj is not defined so define it first say var obj = {a:'Done!!!'}; then put the above line    3. You are done now!!!

Comment: Omg thanks for the typo with the Controller names, but i still haven't this done :S

The objStoredInComponentController   should  be equal to   the  var MyObj  from the Parent

Comment: I did not get you. This is working as per you are expectation. I think you have replaced objStoredInComponentController  by copiedObj and through it you are getting the same values which myObj (which is in parent controller) is having, so where is the issue?

Comment: The issue was fixed, was that i copied double quotes from Dimitar comment, but that double quotes were different quotes and the code crashed ``   "