# ES6 AngularJS move part of the code with inheritance

Tags: angularjs, inheritance, ecmascript-6

i have large `view.html`. And I would like to divide into blocks with inheritance.

I wanted to use the `ng-include`. And to split the common file into several small ones in order to improve the readability of the code. But have a problem with routing.

I tried to use

```
angular.module(...)
  .component('myTemplate', {template: myTemplate})
```

But it does not seem to inherit the parent's data.

Please could you advise the best option for divide on templates? I encounter some problems in the implementation so just i would like to act in the right direction.
Thanks

Comment: Inheritance? Why would you use inheritance for that?

Comment: If your templates are under the same scope as before, then you should be able to access parent data just like the way before

Comment: @Vivz when i use angular.module(...).component - this did not happen

Comment: @Bergi So that I can use the same data as in the general file

Comment: @Lola Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37440727/angularjs-1-5-how-can-a-parent-controller-pass-data-to-a-component-controller and I hope it helps you

Comment: @Vivz Thanks, i will try it right now. Please could you specify - in terms of "correct code" - if I have many such components (more than 5) - this will complicate the readability of the code? Or is it correct use to improve the code?

Comment: Idk it depends on what you are trying to achieve. Suppose you have many divs which you want to remove and put in separate files as templates, and all these divs are in the same scope(ex:having the same controller), then you dont have to create a component , you can just use ng-include alone. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude for more info.

Comment: @Vivz Yes, ng-include it will be great. But one problem with route - i have folder with temples it same folder with view.html. but it not found my files

Comment: Components use **isolate** scope. They **do not inherit** from parent scope.